# Multiline TextField Slick2d

Tags: java, textfield, slick2d

I'm trying to make a quiz game using Slick2d library, and I need a multiline TextField in order to show the question. I have searched a lot this on the web, and in every forum I enter most of the people say that Slick2ds TextField only allows single line.

They recommend using TWL that has a Slick Integration, but it seems that this library is outdated since it gives en Error 503 while trying to view this URL: http://wiki.l33tlabs.org/bin/view/TWL/Integrating+TWL+into+StateBasedGame

Does anyone know how I can make a multiline TextField or how I can use TWL in my already existing Slick2d project?

Comment: fix typos and update wording slightly

Comment: A quick search reveals http://twl.l33tlabs.org/, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, but some of the links appear to be offline.

Answer (score 1):

You have searched in the right direction to create multiline textfields.

The Wiki seems to be off, but you can still find it and browse it here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20130402132022/http://wiki.l33tlabs.org/bin/view/TWL/

The integration with Slick2D is pretty easy. Just be careful because TWL will catch inputs prior to Slick2D.

Comment: When Im trying to acesst his link it gives me this error: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE